# openxlsx - Prevent converting decimal number when reading xlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have problem when reading xlsx which has column types mixed values, the number values is converted to decimal number, (ex: "1.0", "2.0",...)

#### Sample data: [Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pZ-bdpYM9Ga7BKUvQW640IInSBXyr6ILGThfHAijTnc/edit#gid=405373463)

[image]

I download data, save it in local. I use `openxlsx` package (because of the auto detected date)

#### My Code

```
data <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

But result:

[image]

#### Expected result

[image]

How can I prevent this case. It will affect when compare `"1.0" == 1 -> FALSE`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your choice_value column actually isn't a numeric column, but a character column, because in row 3 you ahve a character string "username". You can easily check this with `class(data$choice_value)`. So you should clean up your input first. If your Excel file will always have this structure of mixed data types, you'll always end up with character variables, not actual numbers.

Comment: Thank @deschen, yes, `choice_value` is `character` column. But why and how "1" and "2" coverted to "1.0", "2.0" instead of "1", "2". "you'll always end up with character variables, not actual numbers" I don't think so, uhm, client will fill value is number `1`, number `2`, string `username`, instead of `'1`, `'2`, `username`. They do not understand whether we have broken types after that.

Comment: Not in R way, but change  format cell of `choice_name` from general to number, then it will read

Comment: Thank @Park, yes, it worked. But whether I can prevent them or not, just be precautionary.

Comment: This is a problem within Excel not R. The number is stored as Double value within Excel (eg a decimal number). `read.xlsx` just reads what Excel tell it. :-)

Comment: Thank @Oliver, really? I think Excel have saved integer value, not double :>>>